# Postgres - Evalute join again for every row on the left

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a table `user` which holds my user information. For each user, I want to generate 5 random UUID values.

My initial thought was the following query:

```
select      user.identifier, random.identifier
from        user
cross join  (select gen_random_uuid() identifier from generate_series(1, 5)) random
```

The problem here is that each user now has **the same** 5 random UUIDs.

Is it possible to let Postgres evaluate the `random` cross join again for every user?

**edit**

Postgres doet not support having multiple rows in the `select` clause. For example, this does not work:

```
select gen_random_uuid(), (select gen_random_uuid() from generate_series(1, 5))
from generate_series(1, 5)
```

Comment: not 100% sure if PG supports this, but should do a SELECT user.identifier, (select gen_random_uuid() from generate_series(1, 5)) as identifier from        user should do the job.

Comment: @gorefest See update! This is not supported by Postgres.

Comment: wait a second, should not do this the job? select      user.identifier,  gen_random_uuid()  from        user

Comment: @gorefest I want 5 random values for each user, not just one. I think your query works, but just gives me one single random value.

Comment: thats strange, since the function should be fired for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with u (identifier) as (values (1),(2))
select u.identifier, random.identifier
from
    u
    inner join lateral (
        select gen_random_uuid() as identifier, u.identifier as u_identifier
        from generate_series(1, 2)
    ) random on u_identifier = u.identifier
;
 identifier |              identifier              
------------+--------------------------------------
          1 | c266a1d9-ce87-4fd1-b1fb-d46601ed36d7
          1 | a6cef3ea-48e4-4463-8fab-f8f9dc0535dd
          2 | 3c80e12c-7fb1-4524-88e1-764dcd9049df
          2 | 9d12ae5d-f4be-4330-b78e-38843c440745
```

Comment: LATERAL JOIN, interesting, I did not know that such join existed. Clever solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select identifier, gen_random_uuid() from ( 
select       user.identifier,gs
from         user,generate_series(1, 5) gs )q1
```

Comment: Also good solution. Sorry, I had to pick one solution, and liked the cleverness of the lateral join.